# Android Multi-window - Whats the purpose of android:resizeableActivity @ application level?

Tags: android, resize, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, multi-window

Starting from 7.0 android supports multiwindow mode. To have your app support multiwindow you need to mention this flag in your manifest.

This flag is both available @  level and  level.

1. What's the purpose of having an activity specific flag at application level?
2. If set to true/false @  level does it apply to all activities uniformly?
3. If set to true @  level and if one activity sets it to false then whats which flag takes precedence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the purpose of having an activity specific flag at application level?

It provides a default value for the activities.

> If set to true/false @ level does it apply to all activities uniformly?

Yes.

> If set to true @ level and if one activity sets it to false then whats which flag takes precedence?

If the activity specifies the flag, the activity's flag affects that activity. Otherwise, the activity uses whatever the application set, or a system default if the application did not set it.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer within my experience working with 'windowSoftInputMode'.
1. I think is for having a determined action by default.
2. For our case it did. 
3. When we are working with resize for screensoft it was the activity. For example all activity were set to "adjust Nothing" and a activity with input text was set to adjust, so the layout resize so soft keyboard would fit at screen.

That is a very curious question.